# Bazel: hermetic use of jar command?

Tags: bazel

We have a custom Skylark rule that invokes `jar` after using the Thrift compiler to generate `.java` files, modeled after [genproto.bzl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/build_rules/genproto.bzl#L68:L74).

What is the recommended way to invoke an external `jar` command in a hermetic way? Should we use [`new_http_archive`](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/workspace.html#new_http_archive) to pull in the JDK archive (and how would this work with the DMG Oracle provides for OSX) with something like [jdk.BUILD](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/tools/jdk.BUILD)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have @local_jdk//:jar that expose the jar binary coming from the jdk used by Bazel.

Comment: I was able to get this to work if I also added `@local_jdk//:jdk` to the inputs. See the explanation in `genproto.bzl`[1]. Currently, if `@local_jdk//:jdk` is not present, jar will not have all of the system libraries it needs available.

[1]: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/50e7e7f89a985de944e8b966ee0f827b39c91666/tools/build_rules/genproto.bzl#L75:L83

Comment: Yes we have a fix at HEAD about the need for @local_jdk//:jdk that should work.